# Gremlin query for getting all the distinct values of a property from all the vertices

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have an app which stores system data in RDBMS and the customer's data in Neptune db.
Whenever a customer is onboarded, its entry is added in RDBMS and all the data the customer creates is persisted in Neptune db.

The app supports multi-tenancy, so, the data for all the customers is persisted in the same Neptune db but with an identifier on all the vertices and edges.

a property named "resourceId" is added to each vertex and edge for relating this data to a particular customer present in RDBMS.

When these customers are offboarded, the entry is marked as deleted from RDBMS and a background task is started to purge the edges and vertices based on this property.

But in the case when RDBMS entry is lost, there is no way to identify orphan data in Neptune db for cleanup.

To purge this orphan data I want to query distinct values of this property present in the db and then perform an intersection with RDBMS data to find orphan resourceIds. And later use them to delete it from Neptune db.

Is there a way to get all the distinct values of a property present on the vertices using Gremlin?

I know it may cause performance issues but it is a kind of utility that will not run frequently.

Answer (score 0):

To get distinct values in Gremlin, you will typically use the `dedup` step. So something like:

```java
g.V().values('key').dedup()
```

As you observed, in a large graph this may take a while to complete.